# What is the advantage of optical astronomy over infrared astronomy in space telescopes?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, space-telescope, infrared

The Habitable Worlds Observatory, the proposed successor to the James Webb has an identically sized 6.5 meter mirror but operates primarily in visible light. Infrared telescopes like Webb have the benefit of making otherwise opaque objects transparent  - this seems like a big advantage - why switch back to visible?

Comment: This would be best asked on Astronomy.SE.

Comment: By the name Habitable Worlds Observatory, I'd assume it's looking for a(nother) habitable world, which could only be a planet that is not too far away, so penetration and redshift are not big concerns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search for exoplanets benefits from high resolution. This is because of the small angular separation between exoplanets and their stars.

The resolution of most telescopes is diffraction limited. Bigger aperture -> less diffraction -> higher resolution. Hence the drive for large mirrors.

However, diffraction (therefor resolution) is produced by the relationship between wavelength and aperture. Longer wavelength -> more diffraction.

JWST has a much larger mirror than Hubble. But because it looks at wavelengths which are about 10 times as long, JWST's resolution is much lower then Hubble's. ( 0.1arc-sec vs 0.04 arc-sec).

[image]
https://www.vox.com/science-and-health/22664709/james-webb-space-telescope-launch-date-december-science-hubble

For a given diameter, a visible light telescope will have a higher resolution than an IR telescope.

Answer (score 3):

> The Habitable Worlds Observatory, the proposed successor to the James Webb ...

The Habitable Worlds Observatory is one of several proposed successors rather than **the** proposed successor. Nothing has been decided yet.

> why switch back to visible?

Different wavelengths see different things, and different wavelengths have both advantages and disadvantages. A key advantage with visible wavelengths is that the sensor does not need to be kept cold. That thermal infrared sensors need to be kept cold is a marked disadvantage.

I'll flip your question around: Why not switch back to visible? The JWST will have explored much of the universe in the thermal infrared by the time it dies. With a telescope of similar capabilities to the JWST, there will probably be much more to be discovered at other wavelengths compared to making a replica of the JWST.